# Is it risky to use drush command in your custom module?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drush

I want to run SQL query using drush sqlq command in my custom module and want to export data in a csv file.

```
drush sqlq “select nid, title from node_field_data” > test.csv
```

This is working fine but is it risky to use on live project? Or can it be a security vulnerability?

Please suggest.